# Meteor ReactiveVar access parent tempate from child template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have parent template included with child template. I need to use parents `ReactiveVar` from child template. I can use `Session` method but for my requirement `Session` method doesn't works. How do I access ReactiveVar value from parent templates?

**HTML:**

```
<template name="ParentTemplate">
   {{> ChildTemplate}}
</template>

<template name="ChildTemplate">
 //Some HTML content
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.ParentTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.myvalue = new ReactiveVar(5); //I tried this.data.myvalue but doesnt works
});
Template.ChildTemplate.helpers({
 'myhelper' : function(){
   return Template.parentData(1).myvalue.get();
 }
});
```

Comment: in the parent template, put the data in the `Template.currentData()` context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example were the child is a direct descendant of the parent:

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> child}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  <p>{{parentValue}}</p>
</template>
```

In this case we can access the parent's instance variable like this:

```
Template.child.helpers({
  parentValue: function() {
    var parentView = Blaze.currentView.parentView.parentView;
    var parentInstance = parentView.templateInstance();
    // replace parentVariable with the name of the instance variable
    return parentInstance.parentVariable.get();
  }
});
```

If the two templates have a more complex relationship in the DOM, you can use something like this:

```
// replace .parent-class will the selector for your parent template
el = $('.parent-class')[0]
var parentInstance = Blaze.getView(el).templateInstance();
// replace parentVariable with the name of the instance variable
return templateInstance.parentVariable.get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are my `teacher` who answered my many questions.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution could be to pass the data to the child explicitly.

```
// js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.parent.onCreated(function () {
        this.reactiveV = new ReactiveVar(42);
    });

    Template.parent.helpers({
        getReactiveVar: function() {
            return Template.instance().reactiveV;
        },
    });

    Template.parent.events({
        'click button': function(e, tmp) {
            tmp.reactiveV.set(tmp.reactiveV.get() + 2);
        },
    });
}
```

and in the template file:

```
<template name="parent">
    <p>this is the parent!</p>
    <button> var++ </button>
    {{> child parentData=getReactiveVar}}
</template>


<template name="child">
    <h3>
        child template
    </h3>
    {{parentData.get}}
</template>
```

as you press the button you will see the child template update. If you needed to, you could also assign the parent data in some other way in the `Template.child.onCreated` function.

This might provide loser coupling between the two templates.